# using DevicePolicyManager resetPassword succeeded,but unlock the screen failure

Tags: android, screen-lock, reset-password, device-policy-manager

I developing a DeviceManager sample app,and i use resetPassword() method to reset screen lock password.
using some long length password,just like "123456"、"abcdef",this method result tells succeeded,and working good on screen lock.

using some short length password,"11" or "ab",the method result still succeeded,but not working on screen lock.
and strangely,when i input wrong password,some screen text show that is wrong password,then input correct password,it doesn't show any text,just no response.

for this problem,i have restored factory defaults three times。

Comment: What Android version are you using? What does `getPasswordQuality(ComponentName)` and `getPasswordMinimumLength(ComponentName)` return? See also https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#resetPassword%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

Comment: Android4.4.
and there is two situation
1: I hadn't used setPasswordQuality() or setPasswordMinimumLength before use resetPassowrd(),and it returns true.
2: I use setPasswordQuality() with parameter DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHANUMERIC.then I reset a short password and not fit this quality,it also returns true.

so does this method resetPassword() result not absolutely right or just not take effect on short password

Comment: seems like this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=resetpassword&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=157230